# Join Case and User in Salesforce (SOQL)

Tags: join, salesforce, case, soql

I'm used to PostgreSQL but very new to SOQL and a bit confused about it. I would like to join rows from Case with rows from User based on User.Id.

I've looked online and tried various solutions but nothing worked out.

Does anyone know I could do that? What type of relationship binds Case and User? Do I have to build a custom relationship between them?

Thanks

Comment: SELECT CaseNumber, LastModifiedById, User.name
FROM Case
WHERE day_only(convertTimezone(ClosedDate))=TODAY

This last User Name column is the join I do not manage to make. I would like to show the name of the user that the LastModifiedById refers to.

Answer (score 0):

[SOQL supports joins](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) by following the relationship from the FK (using the relationship name), many of the schema explorer tools (SoqlX, Workbench, etc) will help you discover these and build/test SOQL queries.
In this case you want something like

```
select CaseNumber, LastModifiedBy.Name from Case Where ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did find this relationship meanwhile and the explorer tools you mention will help me understand the relationships I will have to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/soql-join-between-two-standard-objects

```
 Select CaseNumber, LastModifiedById, (Select name From User) 
 From Case WHERE day_only(convertTimezone(ClosedDate))=TODAY
```